# How to have multiple Doxyfiles?

Tags: documentation, projects-and-solutions, doxygen, documentation-generation

I am working on a project that includes other 3rd party libraries. All of these 3rd party libraries come with their own Doxyfile, and every of these libraries have their own specific 'Image' folder. Unfortunately some of these libraries are using the same naming conventions to name images.

Due to this reason, if I generate a Documentation for the entire source tree (including 3rd party libraries), it falls in ambiguity due to clashing image-names, and includes images from wrong folder.

How can I use multiple Doxygen files, so each library has its own sandbox? And at the end, the entire documentation output can be interlinked somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the doxygen manual chapter about [Linking to external documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html). It is fairly easy to achieve what you want using tag files.